# Table for History of changes

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database-design

I am working in asp.net MVC 3 Website and I need to keep track of any changes made to a table/entity. Whenever on Edit view something is modified, a list of changes will display with date, changes made columns below that Edit view. Do I need to create another table with entityHistory Name or I need to insert another record in same table for that ?

Please suggest

Comment: "Any" changes?  They're generally called "audit tables", and it's up to your design to store values or deltas.  But changes to the table itself are different.

Comment: I mean when some one updates FirstName, Then I need to keep track that FirstName changed from this value to newValue on this date. IT is for one column

Comment: SQL Server 2008 has audit functionality, but custom stuff using separate tables is common.

Comment: @OMG, how can I know that what columns have been changed If I do using code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you want to do with the history data. If you want to show the record or object graph snapshots I have found creating a History table, with the same columns as the current table, easier to work with in building up how the complete record looked after or before a certain change. This also means that you'll have duplicated tables and data.

If your needs is a pure audit requirement it is easier to have one/two tables that holds data for entity, property, old value and new value columns.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Audit options, SQL Server has now CDC (Change Data Capture in SQL2008) feature which enables developers to trace data changes on a sql table

You can build a similar logging mechanism by using triggers (refer to http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-sql-server-trigger-example-to-log-changes-history.aspx for a sample)

You can also check the following article for an enhanced solution for logging data changes similar to CDC in SQL2005 http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/log-data-changes-using-change-data-capture-for-sql-server-2005.aspx